# limiting the rate of change of an attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, edit

I have a user model. I want to place a limitation of the rate of which the user can change his/her name.

Obivously a person doesn't change a name every day or every week.

How would be best to implement such a limit for example able to change once a month?

The only way I can think of is placing another attributes for each existing attribute so for the `:name` I will created `:name_last_changed_at` and each time I would test it.

Is there a more elegant/rails-way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relate on `updated_at` column and validate it in model.

Comment: This will help limit an update to an entire model, not a single attribute. Maybe the paper trail gem could do

Comment: You're right, sorry. In that case your solution is good, and you don't have to extend your app with more gems.